# Problems initializing new Bootstrap accordion after AJAX request without affecting other accordions

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been researching for a couple of hours and have found numerous similar questions, but none that address my exact requirements or have a solution that is working for me...

I am creating a responsive layout that has two Bootstrap accordions.  Changing the selection in the first accordion should refresh the second accordion using AJAX.  I am using ASP.Net Core MVC, but this question involves JQuery and Bootstrap, and is likely reproducible on various frameworks.  Here is a short version of the HTML:

```
// most of this is omitted for brevity
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                @await Html.PartialAsync("_AccordionOne", Model)
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" id="ajax-container">
                @await Html.PartialAsync("_AccordionTwo", Model[0])
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I initialize the accordions, listen for changes in accordion one, and refresh the partial view for accordion two as needed using JQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var selectedId = 0; // track which record in the first accordion is selected

    // this is needed to style accordions and make them work - I'm not 100% sure how it works, though.
    // obviously this runs only once on document load and does not help me after an AJAX request.
    $('.accordion').accordion({
        collapsible: true
    });

    // detect when selection from first accordion has changed - refresh second accordion using AJAX
    $('#accordion-one').on('click', 'h5.ui-accordion-header', function (e) {
        try {
            var newSelectedId = $(e.target).closest('h5').data('myRecordId');

            if (selectedId !== newSelectedId) {
                // user made a new selection - refresh second accordion using AJAX
                selectedId = newSelectedId;

                $('#ajax-container').load(encodeURI('/MyController/MyAction?myID=' + newSelectedId), function (data) {
                    // choose the active panel on accordion two
                    var activePanelIndex = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < thisPartWorksFine.length; i++) {
                        if (myModel.myItems[i].isSelectedProposal) {
                            activeDealIndex = i;
                        }
                    } 

                    // this part ran on document.ready, but needs to be called again after an AJAX request.
                    // if I leave this out, CSS is not applied to the new accordion two content and accordion two stops working.
                    // however, if I do it this way, ALL accordions are refreshed and the state of accordion one is wrong.
                    $('.accordion').accordion({
                        collapsible: true,
                        active: activeDealIndex
                    });
                });
            }
        } catch(err) {
            // error handling
        }
    });
});
```

My problem is that I need to call `$('.accordion').accordion();` a second time after the AJAX request or the new content in accordion two stops working.  If I call it this way, though, it screws up the state of accordion one.  I would like to do something like this in order to initialize ONLY accordion two, but I haven't found a way to make it work:

```
// does not work - css not applied and accordion breaks
$('#ajax-container.accordion').accordion({
        collapsible: true
});

// also does not work
$('#ajax-container').children('.accordion').accordion({
        collapsible: true
});
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Why aren't you using `this` or some other relative selector?

Comment: @isherwood This needs to be run inside the `('#ajax-container').load()` success callback... I'm not sure what the context of `this` would be in that block of code.  You may be on the right track, but I can't visualize how to use that my advantage.

Comment: I can't help much because I don't know asp.net. I'd think you can simply carry the ID of your outer `one()` method into the ajax callback.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what was wrong with all the different selectors that I was trying, but as usual, I was making things harder than they needed to be.  All I had to do was find the div with `class="accordion"` for accordion two and give it an ID so that it was easier to reference:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion-two">...</div>
```

Then the following code works as expected:

```
$('#accordion-two').accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: activeDealIndex
});
```